# Opening a single CHILD in MDI form

Tags: vb.net, mdiparent

I found the following code from **stackoverflow**

It works correctly when I execute the **MDIParent form as the first form** in the project

```
For Each f As Form In Application.OpenForms
  If TypeOf f Is Form1 Then
    f.Activate()
    Return
  End If
Next

Dim myChild As New Form1
myChild.MdiParent = Me
myChild.Show()
```

I need to open the **LOGIN form as the first form** and open MDIParent.

If I open the login form as the first form the above code it not working.. Need a solution

I added this code to a button control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your Login form as the start form for your project.

On your button, Show the MDI Form (and close the Login form if you wish)

```
MDI_Main.Show()
Me.Dispose()
```

Then to open your MDI Child forms, use the following code:

```
frmChild.MdiParent = Me
frmChild.Show()
```

This is all the code you should need.

Comment: When I use me.dispose() the project stops

Comment: Earlier I used this code, `Dim a As New MDIParent1
            a.Show()` I changed it to `MDIParent1.Show()`. Now the code is working

Comment: If your Login form is your Startup form and you close it, your application will close. You could hide the form with Me.Hide()